# Drawn current in industrial sensors and drivers

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I am asked to build a simple 5 volt to 24 volt adapting circuit.
For this purpose, i need to know the maximum current that can be drawn from industrial sensors and industrial machines drivers such AC motors drivers .
Are they any standards  that define these values?

Answer (score 3):

The current drawn is entirely device dependent. An industrial sensor could draw less than a milliamp or it could draw tens of amps. Ditto for AC motor control circuitry.

The answer is, as always, to read the datasheet. Any sensor or motor driver or almost any electronics you can think of will have a datasheet which tells you the power supply requirements.